# load multi tables into hdfs one time using sqoop

Tags: mysql, hdfs, sqoop

I want to load data of multi tables in mysql into hdfs, the tables' name like a_0_0, a_0_1, a_0_2.

How cqan I Load the data form these tables into hdfs one at a time using Sqoop?

Can I use `UNION`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways that you can achieve this.

1. if you want to import all tables in mysql db, you can use: [import-all-tables](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.1-incubating/SqoopUserGuide.html#_literal_sqoop_import_all_tables_literal) - also you can use this argument `--exclude-tables <tables>` - comma separated values - to exclude some table(s) from `impor-all-tables`
2. if you want to import some data from some tables (meaningful data), you can use: [Free-form Query Imports](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.1-incubating/SqoopUserGuide.html#_free_form_query_imports)
3. if you want to import number of tables, you can right shell script:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh

   i=0
   while [ ${i} -le 5 ]
    do
       echo "importing table a_0_${i}"
       #here write your full sqoop command, this is just an example  
       #sqoop import --connect  --table a_0_${i}
     i=$(( i + 1 ))
    done
   ```

Now run the shell script: sqoop command will run 6 times as per the logic and import 6 tables.

```
$ ./importAll.sh
importing table a_0_0
importing table a_0_1
importing table a_0_2
importing table a_0_3
importing table a_0_4
importing table a_0_5
```

**NOTE:** you will have to modify logic in shell script according to your need. Solutions I am proposing is based on the details provided in question.

Comment: hi, Thank you vary much, I think solution 2 is suitable, because I have 20W+ tables distributed in hundreds of machines, and I have to consider the number of connections of each database. I intend to use union all to union multi tables, do you know how to implement ?

Comment: what do you mean by `20W+` tables? I think for using `UNION` you will have to consider requirement from mysql like column type, and number of  column in each `UNION` clause should match. also consider that `UNION` will export only Unique data, you may want to use `UNION ALL`. Also, option 2 will export all tables to one `hdfs` dir